# Proving $e^{-x}+\cos x=c$ has a solution in $[0,\infty)$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=e^{-x}+\cos x$ be a function. I proved that $\inf f([0,\infty))=-1$. Now I must prove that for all $-1<c<2$ there exists a solution to the equation $f(x)=c$ in the interval $[0,\infty)$.

I tried using the intermediate value theorem, but it holds only for closed intervals. Then I thought that maybe it is enough to prove the statement for some closed interval which is contained in $[0,\infty)$, however then I had a problem with $c$ which can be arbitrary close to $-1$ and at the same time $f(x) \neq -1$ for all $x$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you don't use derivatives? $f' = -e^{-x}-\sin x<0$, $f(0)=2$, $\inf f=-1$; therefore, for $-1<c<2$ there is solution

Comment: @MichaelGaluza $f'$ is not negative everywhere, in part because $\sin$ is often negative.

Comment: @Ian, yes, my bad

Comment: However, you are still OK with your solution, since it is negative in the given interval (-1,2).

Comment: Since you have almost solved the question I will just add a comment to complete the proof. Since $\inf f([0, \infty)) = -1$ and $-1 < c < 2$, it follows by definition of $\inf$ that there is a number $d$ with $-1 < d < c$ and a number $x_{0} \in [0, \infty)$ such that $f(x_{0}) = d$. Now we have $f(x_{0}) = d, f(0) = 2, d < c < 2$ and by IVT we get a number $x_{1} \in (0, x_{0})$ such that $f(x_{1}) = c$.

Comment: BTW I am not sure how you proved $\inf f([0, \infty)) = -1$. Proving this statement is equivalent to showing that for any $k > -1$ there is a value of $x$ for which $f(x) < k$. This is proven exactly using the answer of Jack D'Aurizio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f((2k+1)\pi)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ approaches $-1$ so fast that for any $c\in(-1,2)$ you may apply the intermediate value theorem to the interval
$$ \left[0, \pi(2k+1)\right]$$
for some $k$ that depends only on $c+1$.

Comment: @user246642: yes you are!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track here. It seems like your main problem is that you are trying to fix a single interval and use it for *every* $c$. As you noted, that's a problem, because $c$ can be arbitrarily close to $-1$, so for any *fixed* interval, there will be some $c \in (-1, 2)$ that it can't handle.

However, you're allowed to let the interval depend on $c$. Try experimenting in that direction.